# form_valid and form_invalid never called in django form

Tags: django, forms, validation, authentication

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):


    def clean(self):
        logger.debug("LoginForm: clean")
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        mail = cleaned_data.get("username")
        pwd = cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=mail, password=pwd)

        ...

        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()
        return cleaned_data


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        logger.debug("LoginForm: form_invalid")
        return super(LoginForm, self).form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        logger.debug("LoginForm: form_valid")
        return super(LoginForm, self).form_valid(form)
```

The methods `form_valid` and `form_invalid` are never called. However `clean` is always called (I see the message "LoginForm: clean"). What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing `django.forms.Form` with `django.views.generic.edit.FormView`.

Both `form_valid` and `form_invalid` methods belong to the Django's [class-based generic view FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid).

The `Form` class, which `AuthenticationForm` [extends](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L120), has a [`is_valid` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid) instead.

Comment: Just asking, can I use both of them? One (clean) to make a generic form validation and the other (is_valid) for doing some other stuff?